# Property 'emailId' does not exist on type 'LoginPageComponent'

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-directive

I am trying to validate a html form in angular using Formcontrol validators. But in html file I am getting an error saying "Property 'emailId' does not exist on type 'LoginPageComponent'."

Here's my html and ts code:

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroupLogin" id="contact" (ngSubmit)="checkuser()" method="post">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="Inputemail"><i class="fas fa-user mr-1"></i>Email </label>
                                <input type="email" formControlName="emailId" class="form-control" id="emailId" aria-describedby="emailHelp" required>
                                <span [ngClass]="'error'" *ngIf="emailId.invalid && emailId.touched">Email is Invalid</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="InputPassword"><i class="fas fa-lock prefix mr-1"></i>Password</label>
                                <input type="password" formControlName="password" class="form-control" id="InputPassword" required>
                            </div>

                            <button class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit">Submit</button>
                            

                        </form>
```

Typescript file:

```
initForm() {

this.formGroupLogin = new FormGroup({
  emailId: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
  password: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
})
```

}

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

`emailId` is not a object of your component but of your `FormGroup`.

So you should be using

```
formGroupLogin.emailId.invalid
```

Comment: It's still not working

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in your HTML code you have this:

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroupLogin"
```

and in yout .ts code you have this

```
this.formGroup = new FormGroup({
```

It is not the same form name. formGroupLogin != formGroup

Use same name in both files.

Let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: Apologies! I posted wrong formGroup ts code. It's still not working

Comment: Check if in your .module you have FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule in your imports

Answer (score 0):

The error is completely correct, such a variable does not exist in your component, it is a formcontrol in your form, so you should refer to it accordingly. I like to use a `getter` or then call `get` on the parentform:

```
<span *ngIf="formGroupLogin.get('emailId').invalid && formGroupLogin.get('emailId').invalid">
```